# create an array from Ng-Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 12 ng-models that look like this

```
<div ng-show="selectedHullShip1.Slots.Weapon > 0">  <select ng-model="selectedWeapon1Ship1"  ng-options="Weapon.name group by Weapon.Class for Weapon in weapons | orderBy:'name'" ng-change="calcTotalsShip1()"></select></div>
```

What I need to do is find out which selectedWeapon1Ship1.range (through to selectedWeapon1Ship12.range)  out of the 12 is the longest. I think that creating an array of the 12 items is the way forward (and then checking the array for the greatest value) and I know I have to start of a blank array $scope.range=[], but how do I that please.

for reference my fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/3u6ob98d/10/

Answer (score 0):

From your description I understand that you want to find the weapon with the longest range of the 12 weapons you showed, right?

As you said make a new array containing all your weapons as following:

```
let myArray= [selectedWeapon1Ship1, selectedWeapon1Ship2, ..., selectedWeapon1Ship12]
```

And then find the weapon with the greatest range using Math.max

```
let maxRange = Math.max.apply(Math, myArray.map(function(o) { return o.range; }))
```

Once you found the longest range, then you can get the searched weapon using Array.find:

```
let bestWeapon = myArray.find(x => x.range=== maxRange);
```

This is a way how to get the weapon with the longest range and save it into (bestWeapon). Although Array.find gives you the FIRST matching result. If you want to get all objects with that max range, then you need to use .filter instead of .find.

Comment: the user will select 12 individual weapons from a list using a drop menu, then i need to add those weapons they choose into an array and find which one has the longest range so calculations can be done on it (ie to improve the range further and display the results)

Comment: Then add a .push function to add the selected weapon to the array